# Powershell to Automate login to Website.....$ie.Document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set up a PowerShell that will log me into my sons school portal and submit a required form.  I have to do one daily and got the great idea that I could script it.  the script is below along with the error

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible

$username="Username"

$password="Password"

$ie.Navigate("https://parents.genesisedu.com/hasbrouckheights/parents?module=home&studentid=1000333&action=form")

While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}

$usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('j_username')
$usernamefield.value = "$username"

$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('j_password')
$passwordfield.value = "$password"

$Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName(“saveButton”)[0].value="Login"
$Link.click()
```

---

```
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'click'.
At line:19 char:1
+ $Link.click()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

---

I have tried many variations but can't seem to be able to get it to hit the "Login" button..  Any help would be appreciated...

**************  Webite Info   ************************

```
<input type="submit" class="saveButton" style="color: #000000;background-color: #e0e0e0; font-weight: 500;" value="Login">

<input type="button" class="saveButton" value="Forgot My Password" style="background-color:#e0e0e0; border:transparent; cursor:pointer;color:#000; font-size: 12pt; font-weight:500" onclick="forgotMyPassword();">
```

Thanks

Comment: Remove `.value="Login"`

Comment: SUCCESS ! ! ! ! !! Thank you..  Cause I keep forgetting to fill out that dang form....

Answer (score 1):

You currently assign the string value `"Login"` to `$Link` before invoking `Click()`, hence the error.

Change this:

```
$Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName(“saveButton”)[0].value="Login"
```

... to:

```
$Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName(“saveButton”)[0]
```